# MVC @import html keyword

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to use:

```
<style>@import url("css/main.css");</style>
```

but mvc treats it as .net code in razor view. "CS0103: The name 'import' does not exist in the current context"
how do i fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Double the `@` to fix the issue:

```
<style>@@import url("css/main.css");</style>
```

[More details here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Use two `@@` characters to escape them, that should fix it.