# css @import conflicts with razor

Tags: razor

(Posts such as [MVC @import html keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277356/mvc-import-html-keyword) show similar problems to mine, but the solution does not seem to fix my problem.)

I am trying to use the below code within a .cshtml file. The css @import conflicts with Razor, so I tried @@import but to no avail. I get runtime errors in Visual studio such as "The controller for path '/media/css/site_jui.ccss' could not be found."

```
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @import "/media/css/site_jui.ccss";
        @import "/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css";
                    @import "/media/css/jui_themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css";

        /*
         * Override styles needed due to the mix of three different CSS sources! For proper examples
         * please see the themes example in the 'Examples' section of this site
         */
        .dataTables_info { padding-top: 0; }
        .dataTables_paginate { padding-top: 0; }
        .css_right { float: right; }
        #example_wrapper .fg-toolbar { font-size: 0.8em }
        #theme_links span { float: left; padding: 2px 10px; }

</style>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use double `@` to escape the `@`:

```
@@import "/media/css/site_jui.css";
```

Comment: If this is such an issue then.. why not move it into a stylesheet itself and link that in the view? Why does it need to be placed in the view like this? Also, can you show us the EXACT error Visual Studio gives you when using double @? It shouldn't be giving you an error.. so there's something else going on.

Comment: "why not move it into a stylesheet itself and link that in the view?" - good answer. No specific reason so I'll pursue linking rather than importing.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
   @string.Format("@")import "/media/css/site_jui.css";
```